# Can't include cliext headers (for c++ cli, Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr

Even with a clean empty dll project that is compiled with /clr and only consists of a single cpp file with

```
#include <cliext/vector>
```

and nothing else, the compiler spews

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3331,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3352): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'cliext::BCL_reference<_Cont_t,_Is_ref>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3332,1): error C2805: binary 'operator =' has too few parameters
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3332,1): error C2333: 'cliext::BCL_reference<_Cont_t,_Is_ref>::operator =': error in function declaration; skipping function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3340,1): error C2833: 'operator value_type' is not a recognized operator or type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3341,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3351,1): error C3646: '_Myval': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\iterator(3351,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(872,1): error C2833: 'operator _Mycont_it' is not a recognized operator or type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1083): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(872,1): error C2059: syntax error: 'newline'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(873,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(878,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(878,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_base(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(856): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(883,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(883,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_base(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(856): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(894,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Myenum_it'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(894,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_base(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(856): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(946,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'iterator'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(953,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(960,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(962,1): error C2535: 'void cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::_Insert(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(953): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::_Insert'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(971,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(973,1): error C2535: 'void cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::_Insert(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(953): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_base<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::_Insert'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(991,1): error C3646: 'size_type': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(991,1): error C3646: 'Count_generic': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(992,3): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(991,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1010,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Myarray_t'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1026,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1038,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1048,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1061,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1072,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1129,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1149): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1129,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_select(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1112): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1134,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1134,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_select(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1112): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1145,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Myenum_it'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1145,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_select(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1112): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::vector_select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1194,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1306): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1194,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::vector_select(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1177): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::vector_select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1199,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1199,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::vector_select(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1177): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::vector_select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1210,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Myenum_it'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1210,1): error C2535: 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::vector_select(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1177): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::vector_select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1216,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1223,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1224,1): error C2535: 'void cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::resize(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1216): message : see declaration of 'cliext::impl::vector_select<_Value_t,true>::resize'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1229,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1234,1): error C3646: 'value_type': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1234,1): error C3646: 'default': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1234,29): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '['
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1234,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1245,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1245,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1245,1): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1291,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1296,1): error C3646: 'insert': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1296,17): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1297,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1301,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'iterator'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1363,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1395): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1363,1): error C2535: 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>::vector(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1335): message : see declaration of 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>::vector'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1368,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1368,1): error C2535: 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>::vector(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1335): message : see declaration of 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>::vector'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1379,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Myenum_it'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1379,1): error C2535: 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>::vector(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28117\include\cliext\vector(1335): message : see declaration of 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>::vector'
1>Done building project "test1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This happens with VS2017, VS2019 and VS2019 preview, all newest versions. I'm so confused. This doesn't seem like a bug since it's rather old and proven headers and happens in different compilers.

edit: super duper complete code here (with project files): https://gist.github.com/s9w/a65bf50ed928bd0d6629c1d10b013463

edit: To help the people from the future with the same problem: It's the /permissive- switch (conformance mode) - doesn't play well with that header.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I did. the complete content of the only file is included (that include line)

Comment: Did you include all required headers in to your project? How are you including them into the project currently?

Comment: @Basti 1) It's strange seeing [mcve] being that minimal. Nevertheless, if I try to replicate your results (using VS2019), while having only this header included, when using CLR Library template, or CLR Empty project - I can't reproduce the error. That means, that you are hiding something, about your configuration, in the question. 2) "super duper complete code here" All information, relevant to the question, must be in the question itself.

Comment: huh, I didn't know there are CLR templates - and they work for me too! I can diff the reason myself I think. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help the people from the future with the same problem: It's the /permissive- switch (conformance mode) - doesn't play well with that header.